# Problem with React/Node.js app deployment on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, deployment

I have problem with deployment of my 'TODO APP' on Heroku. I read multiple articles, tutorials and answers on Stack Overflow, but it still doesn't resolve my problem.

This is my `index.js` file in root directory:

```
const express = require('express')
const apiRoute = require('./routes/api/index')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))
app.use('/api', apiRoute)

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'))

  const path = require('path')
  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  })
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000
app.listen(PORT)
```

In the code below you can see scripts in `package.json` for root directory:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
```

In the `heroku logs` I can see, that "concurrently is not found:

```
2020-05-18T19:00:50.438389+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2020-05-18T19:00:50.443535+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-18T19:00:50.444083+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-05-18T19:00:50.444495+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-05-18T19:00:50.444972+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-05-18T19:00:50.446708+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! to-do-app@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"`
2020-05-18T19:00:50.446990+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
```

I have tried multiple things, but none of them work. Any ideas please?

Comment: For some reason, Heroku is trying to run `npm start` which at some point seems to use `concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"`.

Comment: But I don't know what to do with it. Thats why I write here

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: The error is obvious, for some reason, the `concurrently` package is not found.  You should use `npm start` not `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json maybe the script dev is causing an issue.
Try clearing all the scripts and only leave

1. "start" : "node server.js"
2. "test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1"
3. "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"